# Multiple Django Model Queries Changing Independently in One View

Tags: python, ajax, django, django-models, django-views

I have three models being called separately -- one in my first column, the second in my second column, and the third in my third column. The first is the categories and will stay the same. The second is posts and if a category is selected it needs to show those category's posts (if not is shows all), and the third is the selected post (if none, show nothing).

I have it somewhat working with get_absolute_url calls, but I'm using too many (four) different views and it's messy. Also, this way doesn't always function correctly. If I select a post with what I have, the list of posts changes to that category when for example you could still have been in show all posts.

How do I make this work properly? I know ajax would also be good on this but I'd like to get it first working without ajax and then implement it, or is it only possible with ajax?

Here is my relevant code:

**MODELS:**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/category/%i/" % self.id

class Post(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    link = models.URLField(max_length=512)
    dt_published = models.DateTimeField()
    content = models.TextField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/%i/%i/" % (self.category.id, self.id)
```

**URLS:**

```
urlpatterns += patterns('myapp.views',
    url(r'^main/$', 'mainview'),
    url(r'^post/(\d+)/$', 'mainview2'),
    url(r'^category/(\d+)/$', 'mainview3'),
    url(r'^(\d+)/(\d+)/$', 'mainview4'),
)
```

**VIEWS:**

```
def mainview(request):
    category_list = Category.objects.all()
    post_list = Post.objects.all()
    entry = None
    return render(request, 'main.html', {'category_list': category_list, 'post_list': post_list, 'entry': entry})

def mainview2(request, postid):
    category_list = Category.objects.all()
    post_list = Post.objects.all()
    entry = Post.objects.filter(id=postid)
    return render(request, 'mainview.html', {'category_list': category_list, 'post_list': post_list, 'entry': entry})

def mainview3(request, catid):
    category_list = Category.objects.all()
    post_list = Post.objects.filter(category=catid)
    entry = None
    return render(request, 'mainview.html', {'category_list': category_list, 'post_list': post_list, 'entry': entry})

def mainview4(request, catid, postid):
    category_list = Category.objects.all()
    cat_selected = Category.objects.filter(id=catid)
    post_list = Post.objects.filter(category=cat_selected)
    entry = Post.objects.filter(id=postid)
    return render(request, 'main view.html', {'category_list': category_list, 'post_list': post_list, 'entry': entry})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this with just one view.

Additionally you should use the [`@permalink` decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#the-permalink-decorator) in your models `get_absolute_url()` methods. That way you don't risk broken links if you should change your urls.

**models.py**:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('browser', (), {'category_id': self.id})

class Post(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    link = models.URLField(max_length=512)
    dt_published = models.DateTimeField()
    content = models.TextField()

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('browser', (), {'category_id': self.category.id, 'post_id': self.id})
```

**urls.py**:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('whatever.views',
    url(r'^browser/$', 'theview', name="browser"),
    url(r'^browser/(?P<category_id>[0-9]+)/$', 'theview', name="browser"),
    url(r'^browser/(?P<category_id>[0-9]+)/(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)/$', 'theview', name="browser"),
)
```

**views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render

def theview(request, category_id=None, post_id=None):
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    posts = None
    selected_cat = None
    selected_post = None
    if category_id:
        selected_cat = get_object_or_404(Category, pk=category_id)
        posts = selected_cat.post_set.all()
        if post_id:
            selected_post = posts.filter(pk=post_id)

    return render(
        request,
        'template.html',
        {
            'categories': categories,
            'selected_cat': selected_cat,
            'posts': posts,
            'selected_post': selected_post
        }
    )
```

Comment: This is still giving me an error: "AttributeError at /browser/
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'post_set'" Any ideas?

Comment: So I got it to work by putting "posts = Post.objects.filter(category=selected_cat)" instead of "posts = selected_cat.post_set.all()" but I still have one more question. When no categories or posts have been selected it shows no posts, when I would like it to show all. I changed "posts = None" to "posts = Post.objects.all()" but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: The AttributeError can't really be happening with the code the way I wrote it since the get_object_or_404 is guaranteed to either return an instance or raise a 404. Did you maybe introduce an error while adapting my example code?

Comment: You're right, something funky happened when I copied and pasted your code. It's working now. I also put "posts = Post.objects.all()" for when a category hasn't been selected yet so that a user can see all the posts, but when I click a link on there it changes the list of posts to whatever category that was in. Is there a way to make it stay the same if a user is just selecting from the uncategorized list of posts? Thanks.

Comment: How can there be posts without category? Your `categroy` FK on `Post` is non null.

Comment: I can show all posts regardless of category. "Post.objects.all()" does it. That's what I have showing when a user first lands on the page. Categories are just for narrowing down the selection.

Comment: Then maybe I didn't understand your question. You said "Is there a way to make it stay the same if a user is just selecting from the uncategorized list of posts."

What exactly do you mean by that?

Comment: As of now, before anything is clicked, all posts are showing. If a category is selected then the posts change to that category and then if a user selects from that the posts appear and the category is still correct because it was selected from that category. But if someone clicks from the list of all posts before selecting a category, then the list changes to only the posts from whatever category the selected post is in. Is there a way to make it so it still shows all posts if I user clicked a post from the all list instead of a category list?